# pheatmap: cannot access heatmap objects

Tags: r, linux, pheatmap

I have a problem accessing the objects in the created `pheatmap`. please see below my code.

```
library(pheatmap)
set.seed(2020)
mat = matrix(rnorm(200),20,10)
rownames(mat) = paste0("g",1:20)
obj = pheatmap(mat,cluster_cols = FALSE, scale = 'row',cutree_rows = 3)

cl = cutree(obj$tree_row,3)
Error in obj$tree_row : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

```
> packageVersion("pheatmap")
[1] '1.0.12'

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If you restart your session with a cleared workspace and run the exact code above, do you still get the problem? What do you get if you type `isS4(obj)` into the console?

Comment: Thanks Allan it just needed a restart as you suggested.